# How to fix filter by column in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm write project for learning Angular. My project displays posts. I want to filter posts by id and title. I need filtering logic in  post.service.ts. I made filtering by ID (it works fine), but filtering by title works strange. How to fix filtering by title?

All project

posts.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

export interface Post {
    title: string,
    body?: string;
    userId?: number,
    id?: number,
    show?: any,
    user?: string,
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PostService {

    private _postsURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public fetchPosts(page: number, itemsPerPage: number, id: any, title: any): Observable<Post[]> {
        let posts = this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this._postsURL}/posts`);

        if (id) {
            posts = this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this._postsURL}/posts?userId=${id}`)
        }

        if (title) {
            posts = posts
                .pipe(
                    map((posts: any) => {
                        return posts.map((post: any) => { 

                            console.log(post.title.toUpperCase().includes(title.toUpperCase()))

                            return {
                                title: post.title.toUpperCase().includes(title.toUpperCase()) ? post.title : '',
                            }
                        })
                    })
                );
        }
        
        return this.getPageItems(posts, page, itemsPerPage);
    }

    private getPageItems(posts: Observable<Post[]>, page: number, itemsPerPage: number): Observable<Post[]> {
        return posts.pipe(
            map(u => {
                let startIndex = itemsPerPage * (page - 1);
                return u.slice(startIndex, startIndex + itemsPerPage);
            })
        );
    }

    getById(id: number): Observable<Post> {
        return this.http.get<Post>(`${this._postsURL}/posts/${id}`);
    }
}
```

posts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Post, PostService } from '../post.service';
import { User, UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  page: any = 1

  posts: Post[] = []
  users: User[] = []

  columns: any = [
    { title: 'user id', key: 'userId' },
    { title: 'Имя пользователя', key: 'userName' },
    { title: 'Заголовок', key: 'titleArticle' }
  ];

  form!: FormGroup

  public totalItems: number = 100;
  public itemsPerPage: number = 12;

  error = ''

  constructor(
    private postService: PostService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchPosts();
    this.fetchUsers();

    this.form = new FormGroup({})

    for (let column of this.columns) {
      this.form.addControl(column.key, new FormControl(''));
    }

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
      // call fetch for filtering
      this.fetchPosts(values['userId'], values['titleArticle'])
    });
  }

  fullData() {
    return this.posts.map(post => ({
      post,
      user: this.users.find(user => user.id === post.userId) ?? { username: '' },
    }));
  }

  onChangePage(event: any) {
    this.page = event;
    this.fetchPosts();
  }

  fetchPosts(id?: any, title?: any) {
    this.postService.fetchPosts(this.page, this.itemsPerPage, id, title)
      .subscribe(posts => {
          this.posts = posts
        }, error => {
          this.error = error.message
        })
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    this.userService.fetchUsers()
      .subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: _"I want to filter posts by columns."_ What does this mean? Where is the filter logic?

Comment: I want to filter posts by id and title. Filtering logic there are in fetchPosts() in service posts.service.ts

Comment: Why do you use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your array? You're not filtering. You're setting the title of some elements to an empty string.

Comment: You're loading all elements at the beginning. There is no reason to fetch the data again. You could filter the elements in the frontend without new fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the `if` condition as below:

```
if (title) {
  posts = posts.pipe(
    map((posts: any) => {
      return posts.filter(item => item.title.includes(title));
    })
  );
}
```